# Charset black diamond even though php and mysql charsets match

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Can someone please explain something to me, as i'm struggling to understand what i'm doing wrong?

At the moment both of my php/html file and my mysql database have matching Charsets, both UTF-8. My `php.ini` file shows UTF-8 as the default and i'm even setting it in a meta tag just to make sure its definitely correct.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

If i run this code,

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = "my_database";
```

on my database, it returns `utf8` as the character set.

Now I have a column in my database which contains a `£` symbol, but whenever i'm fetching it in php and displaying it on my site, its showing as a black diamond with a question mark inside it.

Why is it not showing the correct characters when both my php and mysql character sets are matching?

**Also, another quick question as i'm quite new to this, what is the current default character set. What should i be aiming to have all of my sites run on? UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or something else?**

Comment: Your database should use `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`. This doesn't affect the `£` symbol but it will affect other things.

Comment: May i know how you connect to database?

Comment: @Zendy The site itself is quite old, so its using php5.6 and `mysql_connect()`

Comment: Change away from PHP's `mysql_*` interface to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` !  See black diamonds in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored